# Microsoft Sign-In Through Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am very new to app development so please forgive me. I have researched far too long and cannot seem to understand how to code my login button for Microsoft sign-in using Firebase. Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref : DatabaseAuth!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }


    @IBAction func logIntapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")
        provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { (credential, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Handle error.
                print("Failed to retreive credential.")
                return
            }
            if credential != nil {
                Auth.auth().signIn(with:completion:)(<#AuthCredential#>) { authResult, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle error.
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Credential is nil.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the credential that you get back from Microsoft, into your call to Firebase Authentication. So something like:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
  ...
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [handling the sign-in flow with the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/microsoft-oauth#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk).